# Where did Fred and George live after they left Hogwarts and started their business?

Tags: harry-potter

Were they still living with their parents, or did they live somewhere near their shop in Diagon Alley?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

## They lived in Diagon Alley, above Weasleys' Wizard Wheezes.

Mrs. Weasley tells Harry he'll have Fred and George's room to himself, since they've moved in above their store.

> “Bed,’ said an undeceived Mrs Weasley at once. ‘I’ve got Fred and George’s room all ready for you, you’ll have it to yourself.’
>
> ‘Why, where are they?’
>
> ‘Oh, they’re in Diagon Alley, sleeping in the little flat over their joke shop as they’re so busy,’ said Mrs Weasley. ‘I must say, I didn’t approve at first, but they do seem to have a bit of a flair for business! Come on, dear, your trunk’s already up there.”  <sub><sup>- Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince, Chapter 5 (An Excess of Phlegm)</sup></sub>

Comment: Another very nice concise answer.

Comment: @Valorum Thanks! :D I'm glad you liked it! :)

Comment: @Bellatrix real Bellatrix is not that nice :O are you Hermione using a charm?

Comment: @lois6b How dare you call me that filthy Mudblood?!? *Crucio!*